# Send Map from SpringBoot backend to Angular View and save it in LocalStorage

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot, local-storage

I'm stuck on the task. I need to send Map from Spring Boot backend to Angular application.

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/dict")
    public Map<String, String> getAll(){
        return dictionaryService.getAll();
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Entity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "key")
    private String key;
    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;
```

```
public class Model {

    private Map<String, String> dict;

    public Map<String, String> getDict() {
        return dict;
    }

    public Model setDict(Map<String, String> dict) {
        this.dict = dict;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Service

```
public Map<String, String> getAll() {
       
        var model = new DictionaryModel()
                .setDictionary(StreamSupport.stream(dictionaryRepository.findAll().spliterator(), false)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(DictionaryEntity::getKey, DictionaryEntity::getValue)));

        return model.getDictionary();
    }
```

In Postman i have:

```
{
    "key": "Some Value",
    "other-key": "Other Value",
}
```

I have little in common with Angular, but I need to do it. The map downloaded from the backend must be saved in localStorage and then downloaded from localstorage taken by the key and the value shown in the view. I don't know how to do it. My solutions, which I do not stick even here, did not work. As I said, I don't know much about Angular. I am asking for your understanding. Can someone please help me? Show the way to a solution or maybe a sample solution.

Greetings !

Comment: You need to send Map from your controller right? Try sending it in responseEntity

Comment: Right, but not necessarily it can also be a Model Object. It's more about how to map the class and service in Angular to read it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service in Angular could be:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class YourService {
  constructor(
      private readonly _http: HttpClient) {
  }
  getDictMap(): Observable<{
    'key',
    'other-key',
  }> {
    return this._http.get<any>('/dict').pipe(
      map(res => res)
    );
  }
}
```

And in your component you can store it in localStorage:

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private sub: Subscription;
  public dict: {key, value}[];

  constructor(private yourService: YourService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.yourService.getDict().subscribe({
      next: res => {
        this.dict = Object.entries(res).map(([k, v]) => {
          return {key: k, value: v};
        });
        localStorage.setItem('dict', JSON.stringify(this.dict));
      },
      error: err => {
        console.error('An error! ', err);
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.sub) {
      this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

In Angular view html:

```
<div *ngIf="dict">
  <div *ngFor="let elem of dict" class="card">
    {{elem.key}}: {{elem.value}}
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't know the keys of your dict object you can insert in output Observable:

```
getDictMap(): Observable<object> {
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer!                                                                                     getDictMap(): Observable<{
    'key',
    'other-key',}                                                                                                          here what if I have a lot of keys, can I do it with loop ?

Comment: getDictMap(): Observable<object> This "object" it means I need to create Class and declare e.q: dict: Map<string, string> ?

Comment: No, object is a generic object. If you know the keys you can also create a model in Angular.

Comment: If you have a lot of unknown keys use Observable<object>. It is a generic type, like in Java.

Comment: Ok, I have it.
but  now what is "this.sub" ?? How can i now display it in html view

Comment: I modified the answer by inserting the complete component.
"this.sub" is the Subscription to be removed once you remove the component.
See in the complete component how I destroy it in "ngDestroy".

You can convert your "dict" object in an array of key/value objects and loop on it in your view. See my modified answer.